# Is there a way to reboot into other windows installation using cmd commands?

Tags: windows, boot, multi-boot

In the System Configuration(msconfig)'s booting tab, I have two Windows 10 Pro installed on the same device, so when I boot the PC it asks which OS to boot.
(Let's say os A is default while B is not.)

Currently, I can reboot into B by manually rebooting, and then waiting for the os list and then choosing OS B instead of A.

Is there a way to reboot into B while using A automatically, i.e. without manual input? For example I would like if there's a cmd script, but I can't find anything related to choosing default OS.

Comment: If you set Option A as the default, and set the timeout to 30 seconds, if you reboot and don't choose Option B within 30 seconds, it'll boot to Option A. Is that not what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command for changing the boot order is
[bcdedit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/bcdedit),
and especially its sub-command
[bcdedit /bootsequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/bcdedit--bootsequence).

Run bcdedit without parameters inside a Command Prompt (CMD)
that is run as Administrator.
This will list all the known boot loaders in the UEFI store
and their identifying GUID.

A command similar to the following will use the GUID to change the
default boot instance :

```
bcdedit /bootsequence e {975a8204-9658-11dd-993e-9aea7965e9da}
```

You should
[disable Fast Startup](https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10)
in both Windows instances to avoid problems.